# CS Module prevents Javascript execution

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, module

Hello guys I have a C# module in my ASP.Net about DoS blocking. The thing is that in my homepage I have a javascript-based carousel. When I'm enabling the module, the page does not load 2 random images of a total of 8 images sliding in the carousel. Here is my module:

```
#region Using

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Timers;

#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Block the response to attacking IP addresses.
/// </summary>
public class DosAttackModule : IHttpModule
{

    #region IHttpModule Members

    void IHttpModule.Dispose()
    {
        // Nothing to dispose; 
    }

    void IHttpModule.Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private fields

    private static Dictionary<string, short> _IpAdresses = new Dictionary<string, short>();
    private static Stack<string> _Banned = new Stack<string>();
    private static Timer _Timer = CreateTimer();
    private static Timer _BannedTimer = CreateBanningTimer();

    #endregion

    private const int BANNED_REQUESTS = 10;
    private const int REDUCTION_INTERVAL = 1000; // 1 second
    private const int RELEASE_INTERVAL = 5 * 60 * 1000; // 5 minutes

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
        if (_Banned.Contains(ip))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }

        CheckIpAddress(ip);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the requesting IP address in the collection
    /// and bannes the IP if required.
    /// </summary>
    private static void CheckIpAddress(string ip)
    {
        if (!_IpAdresses.ContainsKey(ip))
        {
            _IpAdresses[ip] = 1;
        }
        else if (_IpAdresses[ip] == BANNED_REQUESTS)
        {
            _Banned.Push(ip);
            _IpAdresses.Remove(ip);
        }
        else
        {
            _IpAdresses[ip]++;
        }
    }

    #region Timers

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the timer that substract a request
    /// from the _IpAddress dictionary.
    /// </summary>
    private static Timer CreateTimer()
    {
        Timer timer = GetTimer(REDUCTION_INTERVAL);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);
        return timer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the timer that removes 1 banned IP address
    /// everytime the timer is elapsed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static Timer CreateBanningTimer()
    {
        Timer timer = GetTimer(RELEASE_INTERVAL);
        timer.Elapsed += delegate { _Banned.Pop(); };
        return timer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a simple timer instance and starts it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="interval">The interval in milliseconds.</param>
    private static Timer GetTimer(int interval)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = interval;
        timer.Start();

        return timer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Substracts a request from each IP address in the collection.
    /// </summary>
    private static void TimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string key in _IpAdresses.Keys)
        {
            _IpAdresses[key]--;
            if (_IpAdresses[key] == 0)
                _IpAdresses.Remove(key);
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Any errors on navigator's javascript console?

Comment: GET http://website.com/Images/Carousel/image.jpg 403 (Forbidden) is what I'm getting. I'm getting it twice (for each image failed to load)